# Get call log of a particular number

Tags: android

Hello I'm new to android. Please help me to get a call log of a particular number using content resolver in android? The following code gives log of all numbers, But i want to get a log of a particular number. Thanks in advance.

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String order = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+" DESC";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, order);
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String phNum = cursor.getString(number);
        int callType = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(type));
        switch(callType){
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            break; 
        }
        sb.append("Contact:"+phNum);
    }
```

Comment: Because the break exits the `switch` and appends the number to your `StringBuffer`

Comment: @rmnnish : Glad to know my answer helped you. I've now edited the code in the answer though. I moved the calls to `cursor.getColumnIndex(...)` inside the `if(...)` conditional block. This means there's no danger of a `NullPointerException` if the `Cursor` returned by the `query(...)` is null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not something I've ever tried but you need to use the 'selection' parameter of the `query(...)` method to specify the phone number.

Something like this might work...

```
String numberToSearch = "01234567890";
String order = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

// The third parameter is for the 'selection'
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, "NUMBER=" + numberToSearch, null, order);

if(cursor != null && cursor.count() > 0) {

    // If you got this far then you have at least one record
    // for the number you searched for

    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNum = cursor.getString(number);
        int callType = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(type));

        // Do what you need to do with phNum and callType
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the right answer.
The correct answer looks like this:

    String[] strNumber {"0123456789"};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumber , "");

Comment: thrid variable selection args required array of string instead of string alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String order = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+" DESC";
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, order);
int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    String phNum = cursor.getString(number);


   if (phNum.equalIgnorCase("Your Number")
   {
      //here you get particular no call
   }
}
```